# Word value into a key map which has set value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, set

I know what a `map` is and the general basic functions of it, but I don't know why a `set` is being used here instead of just having declared `int i = value` or something similar.

What I'm really trying to do is: after putting the word into the vector, I want to use the same word as a key to a value also. But I really don't know the whole purpose of using the `map` to do that. Not sure if I'm giving enough information but just ask what you need more and I'll reply.

I've only supplied just a the `readWords` function, but if anyone needs the full code, including the header, class, and main file, then I can put them up also.

I partially have the code written down there, with help, but I honestly don't know what it's doing after the `push_back()` function.

```
/* Read word-by-word from filename and store words in text vector.
* Also use normalized version of word as key in concordance map
* The value associated with each key in the map is a set whose
* keys are the associated indices into the vector.
*/
void Concordance::readWords(char * filename){
    ifstream fin(filename, ifstream::in);
    if (fin.is_open()){
        while(!fin.eof()){
            string word;
            fin >> word;
            normalize(word);
            text.push_back(word); //puts word into vector

            set<int> seat;
            seat.insert(text.size()-1);
            pair<string, set<int> > pear;
            concordance.insert(pear);

        }
    }
    else{
        cerr << "Unable to open file datafile.txt";
        exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
    fin.close(); //closes the filename
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you completely understand the requirement for this algorithm. (Is this homework, by the way?)

The goal here is to produce a concordance -- a list of all of the occurrences of each word. The point of the `set` is to hold *all* of the occurrences. (Ex: The word "apple" might appear on pages 1, 73, and 100. So the map entry for "apple" must hold all of those values.)

The point of normalization is to save the reader of the concordance time: "apple", "Apple", and "apples" should all probably be in one entry in the map.

Understanding that, we can update your program.

First, never check for `eof` *before* you read the data. It only makes sense to check for it after you read the data. In fact, there is a much simpler idiom for this check:

```
string word;
while (fin >> word) {
    ...
```

It appears to me that we are required to store the *original* word in the vector, and then use the *normalized* word as the map index

```
text.push_back(word);
normalize(word);
```

Now, updating the map is easy-peasy. You don't need a `pair`, just use the `[]` operator. Realize that merely referencing a map entry causes it to spring into existence!

```
concordance[word].insert(text.size()-1);
```

**EDIT** Breaking that last bit apart:

`concordance[word]` looks up an entry, indexed by `word` in the map. If the entry exists, it is returned. If the entry does not exit, it is created, and the newly-formed entry is returned. `.insert` is the insert operation on the set located by the map entry indexed by `word`. `text.size()-1` is the value inserted into the set located at map entry indexed by `word`.

Putting it back together, `concordance[word].insert(text.size()-1)` looks into the map, retrieves (or creates) the indicated `set`, and then inserts the number `text.size()-1` into that set.

There you go!

Comment: So concordance[word].insert(text.size()-1); is inserting 'word' into the concordance map and then inserting the text size?


I do not need to declare a new set also?

Comment: Yes, `concordance[word].insert(text.size()-1);` is inserting `word` into the concordance map, and then inserting `text.size()-1` into the set. You do not need to declare the new set.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I would vote you up if I could. :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you have made a mistake in copying the code, or whether the code was intentionally like that, but the `seat` set is not used (for other than inserting an element, but since it is not read/stored it will be lost), and all elements added to `concordance` will be pairs `("",[empty set])`

Not it looks like it is trying to build an index, i.e. a mapping from words into the positions in the vector where the word appears. If that is the case, it would probably be better if it was done as:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<int> > concordance;
//...
concordance[word].insert(text.size()-1); // if it does not exists, it will create it
                                         // if it exists it will retrieve it and
                                         // add the new position
```

This pattern is common to index words into pages (for example for a book), where the set has the advantage over say a vector, that it will guarantee uniqueness, if a word appears 100 times in a single page, the set will make sure that the page number is not repeated (you would have to test that in a vector). This is not the case of the code, as the indices are to positions in a vector of words, which are unique in themselves.

Also note, as Nawaz points out, that the loop needs some corrections.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `while` loop is wrong, because the `eof` flag (or any other failure flag) is set *after* an attempt to read from the stream fails; that means, if the attempt to read fails, you try inserting the previously read `word` into the vector twice, and the rest of the code in the loop still executes when it in fact should not.

A more idiomatic while loop would be this:

```
string word;
while( fin >> word ){
   normalize(word);
   text.push_back(word); //puts word into vector

   set<int> seat;
   seat.insert(text.size()-1);
   pair<string, set<int> > pear;
   concordance.insert(pear);
}
```

If the attempt to read (i.e `fin >> word`) fails, then returned `std::istream&` implicitly converts into `false`, and the loop exit.

And I didn't clearly understand the rest of your post, the question and what exactly you're trying to do, so I can't comment on that.